# $\int \left( \frac{1}{t \ln t}\right)^p dt, ~~~ 1\le p < \infty$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, indefinite-integrals

How do I go about finding the following integral?
$$\int \left( \frac{1}{t \ln t}\right)^p dt, ~~~ 1\le p < \infty$$
I honestly have no idea how to solve this

Comment: Have you tried for specific values of $p$, for instance $p=1$? (Note substitution in this case of $u=\ln t$)

Comment: Are you integrating over the positive reals? If you are then this is Riemann integrable and can be solved with the Gamma function.

Comment: @abiessu I know for $p=1$ it is simply $\ln (\ln t) + C$. But doing it for $p$ in general throws me off .

Comment: There is no solution in terms of elementary functions for an arbitrary $p\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $t = e^u.$

Answer (score 0):

Or make a substitution : $u = \ln t$